# Как правильно задать вопрос: КАКОЙ ИЛИ КАКИМ?

Tags: общие-вопросы, согласование

В чём стилистическая разница между вопросами:

> - Какой бывает лес?
> - Какое бывает небо?

и

> - Каким бывает лес?
> - Каким бывает небо?

Answer (score 4):

**Какой бывает лес** (постоянное свойство): лес бывает лиственный, хвойный, смешанный. **Каким бывает лес**: лес бывает таинственным, мрачным, красивым, загадочным.

**Каким бывает небо** (небо все время разное): небо бывает серым, бесцветным, голубым, безоблачным, бескрайним, низким, высоким.

Но это касается вопросов. **При описании могут использоваться оба падежа:** Небо было серое, бесцветное. Зимний лес был таинственным, мрачным. Всё зависит **от желания автора** обозначить временный признак (Т.п.) или не обозначать его (И.п.).