# "КАКАЯ должна быть температура" или "КАКОЙ должна быть температура"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Как правильно написать: "какая должна быть температура" или "какой должна быть температура"? Или, может быть, оба варианта правильные?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429553/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%9a%d0%9e%d0%99-%d0%98%d0%9b%d0%98-%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%9a%d0%98%d0%9c

Answer (score 2):

**Какой должна быть температура (здорового человека)?**

Нормальная температура человека – это  не точная цифра, на «36,6» можно ориентироваться, но отличие на несколько десятых долей градуса не является показателем ненормальности. https://bolitgorlo.com/2017/04/temperatura-tela-cheloveka-normalnaya-nizkaya-i-vyisokaya/

В то же время вопрос  "какая" (форма И.п.) подразумевает такое **постоянство** температуры, а вопрос "какой" (форма Т.п.) допускает некоторое **колебание** температурных значений.

Comment: Не совсем поняла ответ. Некоторое колебание всегда есть. И в случае в температурой тела человека, и в случае с температурой хранения колбасы в холодильнике. Хоть на долю градуса, но колебания всегда есть.
Но речь не о частностях, а о самой конструкции:  "Какая должна быть (существительное в им.падеже)" или "КакОЙ должна быть (существительное в им.падеже)".

Comment: Прочитала схожий вопрос "Какой бывает лес" и "Каким бывает лес". Но там всё понятно, "какой" - виды лесов, "каким бывает" - разные состояния леса в разное время. В моём случае дело другое, - акцент ставится именно на "должен".

Comment: Какая должна быть температура? - 36,6. Какой должна быть температура? Среднее значение температуры 36,6, но возможно колебание на несколько десятых долей градуса. Разным формам вопроса соответствуют разные ответы. Акцент на "должна" тут ни при чем, температура не должна быть точно средней (36,6). По смыслу второй вариант мне кажется более правильным (так как всё имеет допуск), но формальной ошибки нет и в первом варианте, хотя мне он кажется более разговорным.

Comment: "температура не должна быть точно средней" - это как?)) "Средняя" и "должна быть" вообще логически не связаны.
Температура должна быть оптимальной для кого-то (чего-то, каких-либо целей). "Какой (какая) в норме должна быть температура тела?", "Какой (какая) должна быть температура хранения продукции?"

Answer (score 2):

Если в роли именной части сказуемого употребляются местоимения: личные, притяжательные, вопросительно-относительные, указательные, определительные, отрицательные и неопределенные,то возможны формы как именительного, так и творительного падежей. Например: Вы ли это, вы ли это, Рудин? (Т.); - Она моя! - сказал он грозно (Л.); А кто такой Хорь? (Т.); Лиза в несколько дней стала не та (Т.); Каким прикинется, таким себя и покажет (Пауст.)    http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-015.htm

В официально-деловом стиле речи при употреблении составных именных сказуемых  имеется своя специфика. Так, при наличии глаголов — связок (быть, являться, делаться, сделаться, казаться, показаться, остаться, оставаться, стать, становиться и др.) именная часть ставится в творительном падеже.

Это наталкивает на мысль, что такое употребление более нормированное, правильное.

Видимо, всё-таки **оба варианта возможны,** но если мы хотим говорить правильно, как дикторы, лучше употреблять творительный падеж.

Есть мнение, что употребление именительного падежа в составном сказуемом идет вообще на убыль, хотя мы подсознательно пытаемся применять правило:

При глаголе быть, стоящем в прошедшем или будущем времени, чаще употребляется в именном составном сказуемом творительный падеж; именительный падеж характеризует постоянный признак.

(Он был добрый малый...)-всегда был добрый малый, постоянный признак.

Она в семье своей родной казалась девочкой чужой. (А. Пушкин)-временный признак.

Answer (score 1):

Результаты поиска в Нацкорпусе (в газетном корпусе):

"Какая должна быть температура" - 2 вхождения.
Пример:

> У меня лежит три предписания СЭС о том, как надо обрабатывать пациентов, **какая должна быть температура** в операционной, сколько раз мыть руки. [Анна Ахметова. Мэр Ялты посоветовал бюджетникам запасаться провизией – денег до Нового года не будет // Новый регион 2, 2009.10.28]

"Какой должна быть температура" - 10 вхождений.
Пример:

> У нас есть законодательство, которое определяет, **какой должна быть температура** в аудиториях, каким быть освещению. [Александр МИЛКУС. 2,5 млрд. рублей на доплаты педагогам? Да вот они! // Комсомольская правда, 2012.08.30]

Похоже, оба варианта допустимы. Нужно также учитывать контекст.