# Уточнить падеж или часть речи

Tags: грамматика, падежи, части-речи

Возник спор между "знатоками" русского языка.
Есть такая фраза:

> Явка была **высокой**.

Как можно объяснить иностранцу, почему мы выбираем именно "высокой" и что это вообще такое - наречие или прилагательное? или что-то другое? есть ли у этого падеж или нет? если да, то какой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбор такого падежа прилагательного может указывать на *временный* характер качества (в тот раз она была *такой*, она здесь не всегда *такая*).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но как насчет продолжения моего вопроса? Слово "высокой" здесь является наречием, прилагательным или чем-то еще? и есть ли у этого падеж (то есть именно на данный момент какой падеж имеет)? если ответ на мой вопрос уже прозвучал, а я этого до сих пор не понял, то заранее прошу прощения (но я не понимаю все равно)

Comment: Прилагательное, конечно. Но с падежом то же, что у существительных при разных мерах постоянства: "он был депутатом (такого-то созыва)" или "он был глубокий эконом (по натуре)".

Comment: Похожий вопрос на форуме и аналогичный ответ: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429553/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%9a%d0%9e%d0%99-%d0%98%d0%9b%d0%98-%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%9a%d0%98%d0%9c

Answer (score 4):

**Явка была высокой.**

*Была высокой* — составное именное сказуемое, *была* — глагольная связка, *высокой* — именная часть сказуемого выражена прилагательным в форме Т.п.

***Высокий*** — многозначное слово.

Из словаря:

ВЫСОКИЙ 1. Большой по протяжённости снизу вверх;  2. **Значительный по количеству, интенсивности, степени проявления** и т.п.; превышающий средний уровень, среднюю норму. **Высокая активность**.

Answer (score 1):

Явка — абсолютная или относительная, т. е. количественная или процентная, — выражается вербальным образом или графическим, шкалой. Вектором шкалы (более соответствующим представлению о явке) во всем мире считается вертикальный, где *меньше* тождественно *ниже*, а *больше* значит *выше*.

Высокий — прилагательное.

вы-со́-кий. 1. имеющий большую протяжённость от верхней точки до нижней. 2. находящийся на большой высоте. 3. кратк. форма с дат. п.: избыточно протяжённый в вертикальном направлении. 4. перен. имеющий величину больше нормальной или средней. 5. перен. облечённый большой властью или имеющий важный статус. 6. перен. возвышенный, необычный, торжественный. 7. перен., о звуке тонкий, высокочастотный.